# How to work with the results from NSRegularExpression when using the regex pattern as a string delimiter

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm using a simple pattern with `NSRegularExpression` to delimit *content* within a string:

> (\s)+(and|or)(\s)+

So, when I use `matchesInString` it's not the matches that I'm interested in, but the *other stuff*.

Below is the code that I'm using. Iterating over the matches and then using indexes and lengths to pull out the content.

**Question**: I'm just wondering if I'm missing something in the api to get the other bits? Or, is the approach below generally ok?

```
- (NSArray*)separateText:(NSString*)text
{
    NSString* regExPattern = @"(\\s)+(and|or)(\\s)+";
    NSError* error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regExPattern
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];

    NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];

    if (matches.count == 0) {
        return @[text];
    }

    NSInteger itemStartIndex = 0;
    NSMutableArray* result = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) {
        NSRange matchRange = [match range];

        if (!matchRange.location == 0) {
            NSInteger matchStartIndex = matchRange.location;
            NSInteger length = matchStartIndex - itemStartIndex;
            NSString* item = [text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(itemStartIndex, length)];

            if (item.length != 0) {
                [result addObject:item];
            }
        }

        itemStartIndex = NSMaxRange(matchRange);
    }

    if (itemStartIndex != text.length) {
        NSInteger length = text.length - itemStartIndex;
        NSString* item = [text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(itemStartIndex, length)];
        [result addObject:item];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the string before the `and|or` with parentheses, and add it to your array with `rangeAtIndex`.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(.+?)(\\s+(and|or)\\W+|\\s*$)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSMutableArray *phrases = [NSMutableArray array];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
    [phrases addObject:[string substringWithRange:range]];
}];
```

A couple of minor points about my regex:

1. I added the `|\\s*$` construct to capture the last string after the final `and|or`. If you don't want that, you can eliminate that.
2. I replaced the second `\\s+` (whitespace) with a `\\W+` (non-word characters), in case you encountered something like `and|or` followed by a comma or something else. You could alternatively look explicitly for `,?\\s+` if the comma was the only non-word character you cared about. It just depends upon the specific business problem you're solving.

   You might want to replace the first `\\s+` with `\\W+`, too.
3. If your string contains newline characters, you might want to use the `NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators` option when you instantiate the `NSRegularExpression`.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all matches of the regex with a template string (e.g. ", " or "," etc) and then separate the string components based on that new delimiter.

```
 NSString *stringToBeMatched = @"Your string to be matched";
 NSString *regExPattern = @"(\\s)+(and|or)(\\s)+";
 NSError *error = nil;
 NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regExPattern
                                                                               options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                                 error:&error];

        if (error) {
            // handle error
        }

        NSString *replacementString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:stringToBeMatched
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        range:NSMakeRange(0, stringToBeMatched.length)
                                                                 withTemplate:@","];

        NSArray *otherItemsInString = [replacementString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: Although I marked the other answer as the accepted answer, I've used this approach for simplicity.